# What does outputting the filebuf* of an ofstream in C++ do?

Tags: c++, file-io

With an `ifstream` we can output the whole file to `cout` like this:

```
std::ifstream foo("testfile");
std::cout << foo.rdbuf();
```

But what happens when we try to do the same with an `ofstream`?

```
std::ofstream foo("testfile", std::ios::app); // use app to avoid wiping out contents of testfile
std::cout << foo.rdbuf();
```

For me it doesn't output anything.

Is passing the `filebuf*` of an `ofstream` to `std::cout::operator<<` just a useless possibility that has no real usage? Or is there something about it I'm not aware of?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you check the state bits  of `std::cout` after doing this?

Comment: @MohitJain pretty sure he knows that (see first example). The question appears to be what happens when you send a `streambuf` that has no earthly business being sent to a `std::ostream&` to said-target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When executing the `operator <<` overload for `streambuf` insertion as unformatted data, the stream buffer is pulled until it reaches eof, but there is nothing to get to begin with, so...

The result is zero characters will be written. Per the standard (C++14 § 27.7.3.6.3/9), in such a case the fail-bit it set on the target output stream, and is evidenced by the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream foo("testfile", std::ios::app);
    std::cerr << std::boolalpha << std::cout.fail() << '\n';
    std::cout << foo.rdbuf();
    std::cerr << std::boolalpha << std::cout.fail() << '\n';
}
```

**Output**

```
false
true
```

And yes, in this case it is not only useless, it renders the target `ostream` useless until its fail-state is `clear()`ed.

Best of luck.

Comment: I still wonder why they made it possible to pass an output-only `streambuf` to `cout`, and not limit the parameter to something like an `inputstreambuf` instead...

Comment: @zenith you're not the only one. Apparently that isn't how the `basic_streambuf<charT,traits>` wheel spins. 27.6.3 is a pretty good read, and the [cppref article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) on stream buffers is *outstanding*.